# Shapely with IronPython 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, shapely

Will Shapely run with IronPython 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

ref: https://sgillies.net/2009/02/19/plugins-for-shapely.html

> In theory, this makes it possible to a write an application using Shapely that can run on either C Python, Jython, or IronPython using the appropriate backend for the platform, as long as setuptools and pkg_resources work.